# Express js server giving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

i'm having a serious issue with an app i'm building with node.js and express.js.
the app converts videos to mp3. when the video is small upto 5min length everything work as expected, the http server respond with a download button to the client.
but when the video is too big the server prematurely closes connection, and because i'm using http protocol, the client retry the request and this time receives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after a certain amount of time of waiting.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {    

    var obj_dlConvert = apart_dl_cv.dlConvert(req.body.yt_url,140,apart_dl_cv.generateDir()); //the function that download from youtube and convert
    var lien = obj_dlConvert.link;
    var dossier = obj_dlConvert.dossier;
    var video_stream = obj_dlConvert.streame;

    obj_dlConvert.processus.on('end', () =>{
        fs.rename(path.join(__dirname,'uploads',dossier,dossier+'.mp3'), path.join(__dirname,'uploads',dossier,'video.mp3'), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('dlpage.hbs',{
                    renameError: true                 
                });
            }else res.render('dlpage.hbs',{
                dossier: dossier,
                fullLink: lien
            });
        });           
    }        
 }

 req.on("close", function() {
     obj_dlConvert.processus.kill();
     obj_dlConvert.processus.on('error', () => {
         if (fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname,'uploads',dossier))){
             fse.removeSync(path.join(__dirname,'uploads',dossier));
         }
     }); 
 });
```

});

Comment: Some code would be useful......

Comment: Can you also add the route handler that handles the actual downloads of the files?

Comment: hi @JeremyThille here is some code, and thank you for your help

Comment: hi @robertklep, here is it app.post('/', function(req, res) {} and thank you in advance

Comment: @sparpar it looks like you're rendering an URL to the converted MP3 file; which Express route is handling those URL's?

Comment: @robertklep with this code everything work fine, the problem begins when the videos are big. in that scenario : req.on('close') gets called after a certain amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Serving video is not a one time deal. There is a hand-shake between the browser and server. The server needs to be able to provide the 'next' chunk when asked by the browser. Following may by used as an inspiration:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
http = require("http"),
url = require("url");

exports.serveVideo = function(req, res, file) {
 var range = req.headers.range;
 var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
 var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);

 fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
   var total = stats.size;
   var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
   var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

   res.writeHead(206, {
    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": chunksize,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  });

var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: start, end: end })
  .on("open", function() {
    stream.pipe(res);
  }).on("error", function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });
});
}
```